# wpf enable control on lost focus

Tags: wpf, vb6, focus

I have a simple wpf application that consists of 3 textboxes (tx1 enabled, tx2 disabled and tx3 enabled) plus one more textboxes which are not relevant here.

Depending on the content of tx1, I would like to enable tx2. I do this check in tx1_LostFocus and set tx2.IsEnabled to True.

I would expect to have my cursor in tx2 after leaving tx1, but this is not the case, I always find the cursor in tx3, although tx2 is enabled after the action is over. I assume the focus manager simply has tx3 as target and enabling tx2 comes too late.

All tries using PreviewLostKeyboardFOcus did not help.

Please take into account that I have to do a legacy software transfer from vb6, so I cannot use bindings or validation using IDataErrorInfo, I simply have force the cursor like described.

Any clue?

Comment: And after enable tx2, why cant you call FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(parentElement, tx2) or better yet tx2.Focus() in the tx1.LostFocus handler

Answer (score 1):

On lost focus event of tx1 make is enable of tx2 true and then set focus on tx2 and add some delay on this thread using dispatcher or thread.threading.sleep() and in your xaml binding give update source trigger= property changed.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is as expected.  When your LostFocus event fires, focus has ALREADY moved to the next (enabled) control in the tab order.  Because you're not enabling the next textbox in the sequence until after you've already moved focus along the tab index order, the control you want to have focus is skipped, since it's disabled.

You have two choices to get your desired behavior:

1. Move your validation code to an event that fires BEFORE LostFocus
   (so that when the user presses tab, the control would already be
   enabled and therefore will be hit as the next control in the tab
   index order) such as Validate or Change
2. Leave the validation code where it is and do as Gilberto and Kumar
       suggest by specifying where focus should move programmatically (i.e.
       call txt2.SetFocus() at the end of your validation code in the
       LostFocus event)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I do not think that there is a Validate event in WPF anymore, and doing validaiton on Chnage is not possible as we use db requests here.

Comment: You're right, in WPF there isn't a Validate event, sorry, missed the WPF tag originally.  But in that case, the 2nd option to FORCE focus to move where you want at the end of the LostFocus event sounds like you're only choice.  As for not possible to validate in the OnChange event, that's a design decision, not a limitation (you really should validate input before you just throw it at the db...)

Comment: Eric, you are right, validation is the problem, but we validation itself need db access, so Changed event does not help

Comment: I guess I don't understand why doing one thing in an event, precludes you from doing MORE than one thing.  If you already have the validation occurring the in Changed event, is it really impossible to add the one extra line to that method to .Enable the textbox you need? That way you still get your validation, the necessary textbox is enabled before the current textbox loses focus (which is why you're having this issue in the first place) and everything works as expected.

Comment: Eric, you got me wrong: I cannot use the changed event for validation because we have massive db requests there we cann ot fire on each keystroke. But I think I have a solution using LostFocus and dispatched SetFocusedElement calls as proposed earlier. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the "Tabindex" property?
Also you caan use on lost focus event: "tx2.setfocus" and so...

Comment: Tab index just changes the order of the stops, and does nothing if one of the stops happens to be disabled, like in the op's question.